# Install Ubuntu in my Windows laptop in c drive without lost my data

Tags: system-installation, windows-8

I am New to Ubuntu.
I'd like to install ubuntu on my laptop. Right now I am using windows-8.1

my drive iis partitioned into 4 parts C:,D:,E:,F:

I want to install ubuntu in C:\ drive without lose of my data on the other drives.

is that possibale...
help me

Comment: Yes it is possible. I'll edit the question so it doesn't become a really messy writing.

Comment: Can you atleast accept my edit?

Comment: Ubuntu dose not have a C drive, why are you calling it this ? Is Windows installed there ? I that case, Ubuntu would over write Windows and all data will be lost. You need two partitions for Ubuntu, one for the system and one for swap. Please boot a live USB of Ubuntu and run `gparted`, now screen shot this and upload it here so we can see your partitions and help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Open disk management in windows and try create unallocated (black) space from other partitons. Boot ubuntu from USB/CD and click Install Ubuntu. If you see "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1" you can start installing. Windows boot loader will be disabled and replaced with GNU GRUB. You can still boot windows by selecting Windows 8.1 loader

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to install it in a Virtual Machine. In that way you will not mess the partitions and put your data in jeopardy. Linux would behave as just another application in Windows.

I would recommend Virtual PC from Microsoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3702) or VirtualBox from Oracle (https://www.virtualbox.org/).

When you learn more about Linux and when you know you want to use it more, then I would suggest exploring dual boot possibilities.

Comment: INSTALL Ubuntu ON MY WINDOWS LAPTOP. This does not answer the question how the user wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I installed Ubuntu 15.10 2 days ago (22 dec,2015). I had Windows 8.1 installed in C: drive. I created bootable usb stick and ran Ubuntu 15.10. But i didn't get "Install ubuntu along side Windows". So I loaded Windows 8.1 , moved all the files from drive D: to drive E: , reduced the size of drive D: to 85 GB and added remaining space to drive E:.

Then i booted my laptop from usb and installed Ubuntu 15.10 to drive D:.

(I suggest reducing the size of drive D: to 30 GB as it becomes invisible to Windows 8.1)